# Can I enable selection / grabbing of transparent objects in Fabric.js?

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

I've noticed that if I set the `fill` of an object to say, `rgb(0,0,0,0)`, I can't "grab" the object for drag and drop. Is there a way to allow selection of a transparent object?

I'd like to create a transparent box around a text object so that the text can be grabbed even in between the letters.

Comment: *text can be grabbed even in between the letters*. What does it mean? Have you enabled `perPixelTargetFind` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this for now by setting the alpha to 0.01, which makes the object practically transparent, but still selectable